# How to call MainWindow class from another Qt Widget form class

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display a dialog at startup of my program, For this purpose I create a new Qt Designer Form Class called `Dialog`.
In main.cpp I have the following code which executes the `Dialog` class:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dialog diag  ;
    diag.show() ;

   return a.exec();
}
```

The `Dialog` class contains an "OK" button. When user pushes that button the Dialog Window close and the `MainWindow` opens. For this I code it like this:

```
void Dialog::on_ok_butt_clicked()
{

   MainWindow w ;
   w.show() ;
}
```

but the MainWindow window not displaying... 
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change `MainWindow w ; w.show();` to `MainWindow* w= new MainWindow; w->show();`

Comment: hi ... tnx for the reply ... can you tell me the difference

Comment: A local variable is destroyed when the function ends, so your window will be deleted. On the other hand if you store the position of the memory it will remain, but your duty is that when you do not need it you will have to eliminate it.

Comment: can i declare it in the main or in some header extern way for the parent child purposes and in the ok_push_buuton slot just call show()? as the Kanan proposed is it not well to handle it this way ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, what are you going to do in your QDialog?

Comment: @Parano, seeing a mainwindow does not mean  a good code! `a good answer should have a quality solution` .. even if you create a pointer to mainwindow inside dialog object .. when your dialog object expires .. how can you reference your mainwindow?

Comment: @MohammadKanan that's why it depends on the use that it gives to the program, and since the author does not give a broader context I only give a possible solution, I have not published it because I think the author has not given adequate information.

Comment: @eyllanesc, no problem. most qt new programmers are not aware of  good design practices .. thats why I did not include code in my answer ..

Comment: guys tnx for your all answers ... can i declare class in the extern way

Comment: my application used high performance opencv tasks so it is pretty important for me to how to declare MainWindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in the lifetime of objects. In on_ok_butt_clicked() you create MainWindow object. And after you return from on_ok_butt_clicked() MainWindow object will be destroyed.

You need to create an object so that it remains after exiting on_ok_butt_clicked() method. Another option is to stop the execution of the method when displaying dialog (this is unapplicable to QMainWindow, because QMainWindow inherits from QWidget, not from QDialog).
First solution:

```
MainWindow *w = new MainWindow(this);
w->show();
```

Second solution:

```
SomeDialog w;
w.exec();
```

Comment: MainWindow does not have the exec method.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. MainWindow inherits from QWidget, not from QDialog.

Comment: Edit your question and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your way the dialog object is the parent of your mainwindow, thats not good design because dialog is usually a temporary object while mainwindow will be your main UI, so I prefer to create the dialog inside your mainwindow, when you want to show the dialog `hide()` the mainwindow first and dont forget to either `accept()` or `reject()` your dialog

Comment: well ... i test this to ... but when i add the following   Dialog diag ;   diag.show() nothing happens neither